# Find the loop invariant of the given while loop

Tags: proof-techniques, loop-invariants, hoare-logic, proof-assistants

I don't know how to find a loop invariant.  I'm not sure where to start.  Can anyone find the loop invariant of the given program and explain your method please.

```
{n ≥ 0 ∧ i = 0}
while i < n − 1 loop
b[i] := a[i + 1];
i:=i + 1
end loop
{∀j.(0 ≤ j < n − 1 → b[j] = a[j + 1])}
```

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? If you don't know where to start, that usually means you need to go back and review your lecture notes.

Comment: The invariant expresses that the array copy has been partially performed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end of each iteration you have 
$$
\forall j: 0 \leq j < i \implies b[j] = a[j+1]
$$
which you can prove by induction. Thus, when the algorithm terminates, $i$ has reached $n-1$ and you have 
$$
\forall j: 0 \leq j < n-1 \implies b[j] = a[j+1]\,.
$$

I figured this out by just asking myself what kind of statement I can make at the end of each iteration. In this case it's that the first $i$ elements have been copied. Then I just turned that into a formal statement.

Comment: In general if you are trying to end up with post-condition `R(n)` then at the end of each iteration you may have `R(i)` ;-)